# tabEndNewRow deletes value of last cell

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Tabulator documentation [tells](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/navigation) us that

```
The tabEndNewRow option will cause the table to create a new 
row and add focus on the first editable cell in that row when
you tab out of the last editable cell on the table. You can 
set it to one of a number of options to determine the data of 
the new row.
```

but in my code the tab pressed on last cell if it is editable it DELETEs the cell's value

```
    var cols = [{
        title: "Cell 1",
        field: "c1",
        editor: "input"
      },
      {
        title: "Cell 2",
        field: "c2",
        editor: "input"
      },
      {
        title: "Cell 3",
        field: "c3",
        editor: "input"
      },

    ];

    var row = {
      "c1": "",
      "c2": ""
    }
    var table = new Tabulator('#table', {
      columns: cols,
      data: [row],
      height: "100%",
      tabEndNewRow: row,
    })
```

Working jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/radek/xe4qbL5k/6/

would you have any solution for that issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think you found a bug in Tabulator.  In version 5.1.0 if you look at the not-minified version you can see the line

```
// cell.getElement().firstChild.blur();
```

commented out on line 13359.  Commenting this line out causes the new row to be added before the changes to the current row are processed.  I checked version 5.0.10 and it did not have that line commented but it shows some other errors.  With 4.9.3 your fiddle works fine.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5140nkxm/)

Comment: @Radek  This is the correct answer.  It is not deleting the value of the last cell.  It is never making the change because that is triggered by the blur event.  You can test this in your fiddle by entering data in the last cell and clicking somewhere else.  Then go back into the last cell (change it if you like) and hit tab.  You can uncomment the line and host the js yourself instead of using the CDN but who know why it was commented out. Perhaps it causes a problem with some other new change.  Unless you need functionality that was introduced after 4.9.3 your best option is to go with that.

Comment: This issue has now been resolved in the 5.1.4 release